# Installation of appium through npm is taking too much time

Tags: node.js, npm, appium

i am trying to install appium through npm.
below are my npm and node version

```
npm-3.10.3
Node-v6.3.0
```

i run below command

```
npm install -g appium --loglevel=info
```

it just get stuck after the last line

```
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-fullwidth-code-point/-/is-
fullwidth-code-point-2.0.0.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-bom/-/strip-bom-
3.0.0.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/path-type/-/path-type-
2.0.0.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/load-json-file/-/load-json-
file-2.0.0.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/os-locale/-/os-locale-
2.1.0.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/which-module/-/which-module-
2.0.0.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string-width/-/string-width-
2.1.1.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs/-/yargs-8.0.2.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs-parser/-/yargs-parser-
7.0.0.tgz
**[    ..............] / loadRequestedDeps: http fetch 200 
https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs-parser/-/yargs-parser-7.0.0.tgz**
```

Comment: Might want to upgrade npm first. `npm install -g npm`

Comment: did n't helped..it still hangs on some other point

Answer (score -1):

- ```
    Change npm's default directory: If you don't want to use sudo, you can configure npm to install global packages in a directory where your user has write permissions. To do this, you can create a directory for global npm packages in your home directory and configure npm to use it. Here's how:
  ```

  - Create a directory for global npm packages in your home directory: sh  Copy codemkdir ~/.npm-global
  - Configure npm to use this directory for global packages: sh  Copy codenpm config set prefix ~/.npm-global
  - Add the ~/.npm-global/bin directory to your PATH by adding the following line to your shell profile file (e.g., ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.zshrc): sh  Copy codeexport PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
  - After making these changes, you may need to restart your terminal or run source ~/.bashrc (or the appropriate profile file) to apply the new PATH configuration.
  - Now, you should be able to install global packages without using sudo: sh  Copy codenpm i appium -g
- ```
    Use a Node Version Manager (NVM): Another approach is to use a Node Version Manager like NVM, which allows you to install and manage Node.js and npm without requiring superuser privileges. With NVM, you can switch between Node.js versions and install global npm packages without the need for sudo. You can install NVM following the instructions here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
  ```

Choose the method that best suits your needs and security considerations. It's generally recommended to avoid using sudo for npm commands whenever possible to prevent potential issues with system permissions.

Comment: Simply do this : 
Step1: mkdir ~/.npm-global
Step2: npm config set prefix ~/.npm-global
Step3: export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
Step4: npm i appium -g

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).